# How to perform web scraping for website with login

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

'''
I would like to perform web-scraping for website which requires login. I tried two different code approach. Still I am unable to perform login.
'''
#Develop code in Python using BeautifulSoup:

#First Approach
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import http.cookiejar
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

```
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

authentication_url=
```

'http://127.0.0.1/orangehrm4.3.1/symfony/web/index.php/auth/login'

```
payload = {'txtUsername': '<username>', 'txtPassword': '<password>'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode("utf-8")

req = urllib.request.Request(authentication_url, data)

resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

contents = resp.read()
```

#Second Approach

```
import requests
from lxml import html

USERNAME = "<USERNAME>"
PASSWORD = "<PASSWORD>"

LOGIN_URL =
"http://127.0.0.1/orangehrm-4.3.1/symfony/web/index.php/auth/login"

URL = "http://127.0.0.1/orangehrm-4.3.1/symfony/web/index.php/dashboard"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Getting login csrf token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    crsf_token = 
    list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='_csrf_token']/@value")))[0]

    payload = {
        "txtUsername": USERNAME, 
        "txtPassword": PASSWORD, 
        "_csrf_token": authenticity_token
    }

    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = 
    dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

    #URL to scrape
    result = session_requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div', id='branding')
    print(div)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

'''
After using these methods, we are only able to get data for the login page. I assume that we are not able to login as I want to access data of pages after login.

It would be very helpful to figure out how web scraping can be performed after getting logged in into the website using Python, BeautifulSoup.
'''

Answer (score 0):

Try to use authorization methods which is available instead of using payload methods. For example here am using HTTPBasicAuth

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
USERNAME = "<USERNAME>"
PASSWORD = "<PASSWORD>"
BASIC_AUTH = HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
LOGIN_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/orangehrm-4.3.1/symfony/web/index.php/auth/login"
response = requests.get(LOGIN_URL,headers={},auth=BASIC_AUTH)
```